# is it possible to select a group of objects through click and drag in HTML5?

Tags: html, multi-select

I'm working on a flex application that has a behavior similar to visio: by holding down the mouse and dragging it over several objects you can select them all. We are thinking of moving to HTML5. Will we be able to keep this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with jQuery UI. See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Any idea why? All it does is select the text as it normally would on any HTML page.

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work (you can edit your original question and add it there).

Comment: I just went to the link you provided and tried to select the boxes.

Comment: Click inside any of the boxes and drag to draw a rectangle. Any box whose (partially) covered by the rectangle will be selected.